# class diagram viewer application for python3 source

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, class-diagram

Is there any application which can generate from python3 source something like the below link (i don't care about the representation rather the perfect content)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Searcharoo_3/ClassDiagram.png

Comment: Pynsource is an open source project with free community edition:
https://pynsource.com/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes there is: with [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/) comes [`pyreverse`](http://pythonhosted.org/theape/documentation/developer/explorations/explore_graphs/explore_pyreverse.html) that will generate class diagrams (not as pretty as the one in reference I am afraid, but clear and useful.) There is a dependency with `graphviz`.

### **From command line:**

**To analyse a full or part of a package**

```
$ pyreverse -o png -p <project name>
```

**To analyse one specific file:**

```
$ pyreverse -o png -p myproject \path\to\myproject\myfile.py
```

### **Example output: Class Diagram**

[image]

### **Example output: Packages**

[image]

Comment: is it possible to give a specific file instead of <project name> ?

Comment: I think it is; `<project name>` refers to the folder/package containing a project, but this ought to work if replaced by a specific `<filename.py>`. I linked to the documentation in the answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer anyway... figured out what I need:

pyreverse -o png -p myproject \path\to\myproject\myfile.py

Comment: Great, thank you. I added this instruction to the answer.

Comment: For me the command pyreverse -o png -p <project name> does nothing. Only when I specify filename

Answer (score 6):

I found that the accepted answer violated the principle of least surprise :)

Given a current directory that contains python files as well as source in subdirectories, running `pyreverse -o png -p py_test .` meant Pylint picked up `__init__.py` and then went on to create a UML diagram of `r:\apps\python3\lib\encodings\`.

Using `pyreverse -o png -p py_test ./main.py` generated a blank PNG as no classes where defined within that source file.

However, `pyreverse -o png -p py_subdir ./py_subdir` *did* get some sensible results. It generated both class and package diagrams for all code in the subdirectory. Somewhat counter-intuitive.

Comment: what does py_test represent in this instance?